# В какой момент задаётся кодировка ввода пользователя?

Tags: php, utf-8

Ввод пользователя передаётся на сервер методом POST, затем обрабатывается функцией `htmlspecialchars` и отображается на сайте. `htmlspecialchars` требует чтобы входная строка и результирующий документ использовали одинаковую кодировку. В какой момент задаётся кодировка ввода пользователя?

> Если входная строка, переданная в эту функцию и результирующий
>   документ используют одинаковую кодировку символов, то этой функции
>   достаточно, чтобы подготовить данные для вставки в большинство частей
>   HTML документа. Однако, если данные содержат символы, не определенные
>   в кодировке символов результирующего документа и вы ожидаете
>   сохранения этих символов (как числовые или именованные сущности), то
>   вам недостаточно будет этой и htmlentities() функций (которые только
>   преобразуют подстроки с соответствующими сущностями). Необходимо
>   использовать функцию mb_encode_numericentity(). [Источник](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: 1. На странице с которой идут данные должна быть указана кодировка `utf-8` однозначно. 2. Начиная с версии 5.6 для кучи функций кодировка по умолчанию берется из конфига с настройки `default_charset`. Если не уверены, что админ сервера оставил ее равной `UTF-8`, то в каждой функции указываете кодировку.

Comment: Ну да или воспользоваться функцией `mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');` - для установки и получения внутренней кодировки скрипта.

Comment: Если идти по-тупому, то браузер принимает ввод в поля данных на странице в произвольной кодировке (раскладке), далее браузер "может быть" преобразует кодировку к кодировке страницы (`content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8`), но это не точно. Далее все это дело приходит в POST (url-encoded VS multipart-form-data) на web-сервер, далее web-сервер неким образом это передает интерпретатору, которые делает предобработку переменных и складывает их в суперглобальные массивы вроде $_POST. А уже потом скрипт получает данные. На любом переходе введенная информация может быть перекодирована, в теории.

Comment: Кодировку браузер выбирает исходя из HTTP-заголовков и содержимого head страницы. Кодировку web-сервера можно настроить в его настройках, самое простое - в `.htaccess` строчка про AddDefaultCharset. Кодировку внутри обработчика интерпретатора можно крутить как угодно с помощью того же iconv или mb_convert_encoding. На каждый из случаев есть минимум 10 вариантов, как всегда )

Comment: Если целью является принять данные только в utf-8 без "плохих" символов, то можно сделать такое с входящими данными: 1. `$data = mb_convert_encoding((string) $data, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');` - медленнее, но жрет меньше памяти; 2. `$data = htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlspecialchars((string) $data, ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8'));` - быстрее, но и расходует больше памяти.

Comment: Главный вопрос: это безопасно передавать в `htmlspecialchars` строку в неизвестной кодировке? Насколько я понял безопасно, просто те символы которых нет в кодировке результирующего документа (utf-8) будут утрачены.

Comment: Немного истории http://blog.portal.kharkov.ua/2012/09/16/php54-bug/